# What's the safest TrueCrypt algorithm and hash?

Tags: encryption, hash, passwords, truecrypt

I have an encrypted file container inside my NTFS pendrive. The root folder *Write* permission is blocked for everyone. A folder inside it has all permissions unblocked. The dummy file of TrueCrypt is inside the "full access" folder. It has a 64 characters password, containing… you know… everything and I made a backup to create another file container.

Now, what would be regarded to the potentially "best" (in terms of security) algorithm and hash? Any algorithm and/or hash that I should definitely be avoiding? Or is the choice of algorithm and hash more a matter of personal opinion/preference because there aren’t any real differences between the available choices from a security point of view?

---

**EDIT**

In the end, I used the algorithm `AES(Twofish(Serpent))` with as hash `Whirpool`. To me, SHA-512 is a 2nd place loser. I didn’t choose RIPEMD160 as it’s a DOS-days cipher and – if I’m not mistaken – someone might have found a way to break it? I just didn’t want to take a risk.

Comment: Regarding your choice to use all the ciphers: [Is TrueCrypt's multiple/cascading encryption safe?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6486/is-truecrypts-multiple-cascading-encryption-safe)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All ciphers offered by TrueCrypt (e.g. AES, Serpent, Twofish) are "impossible to break" *to the best of current public knowledge*. Which one of them will be successfully attacked first (if at all) is obviously unknown at this time, hence a matter of personal belief. The same applies to hash functions (SHA512, Whirlpool, RIPEMD160) — there are no relevant weaknesses known in any of them. The standard choice would be AES combined with SHA512.

Comment: RIPEMD-160 is a 160-bit hash, which means collision attacks are sort of feasible to imagine. Should not affect its use in TrueCrypt, but in general I would not say that it is strong.